# Recommended way to set the ELEMENT_NODE position of div?

Tags: html, css

```
 　　#top {
            height: .5rem;
            padding-left: 2.7rem;
            line-height: .5rem;
            color: #666;
            font-size: .12rem;
            position: relative;
            background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
        }

        #top div {
            position: absolute;
            right: .18rem;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            font-size: .14rem;
            line-height: .20rem;
        }

        #top .icon {
            font-size: .28rem;
        }

<section id="top">
    <div>
        allMessages
        <svg class="icon record-info" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="#icon-wenjuan"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>
</section>
```

[image]

I want to set the "allMessages" at the middle of the div.

But When I set the `line-height` to the `#top div`, the "allMessages" always has the same bottom with the `svg`.
 What is the recommended way to set the 'allMessages" text's position at the same height as the middle of the `svg`.

Comment: Try setting the line-height to #top div, and then adding `vertical-align: middle;` to the svg

Answer (score 0):

Update your `code` with following.

```
#top {
    height: .5rem;
    padding-left: 2.7rem;
    line-height: .5rem;
    color: #666;
    font-size: .12rem;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
}

#top div {
    position: absolute;
    right: .18rem;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    font-size: .14rem;
    line-height: .20rem;
}

#top .icon {
    font-size: .28rem;
}
#top span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<section id="top">
    <div>
        <span>allMessages</span>
        <svg class="icon record-info" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="#icon-wenjuan"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>
</section>
```